# PHP loop trying to repeat array string with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code running in CodeIgniter:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($detials);$j++){
    $newValues = array(
        'Description' => $detials[$j]
    );
}
```

currently it outputs this:

```
Array ( [Description] => Array ( [0] => this [1] => is [2] => a [3] => name ) )
```

I want the loop to create this:

```
$newValues = array(
    'Description' => $detials[1]
    'Description' => $detials[2]
    'Description' => $detials[3]
);
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This is impossible. When you ask for `$newValues['Description']` - what should return?

Comment: Yes. You cannot have duplicate array keys. Writing a new value to the same key will simply overwrite the old value.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but I think you may be trying to do this:

```
for($j=0;$j<count($detials);$j++){
    $newValues[] = array('Description' => $detials[$j]);
}
```

Which would give you this array:

```
$newValues = array(
    array('Description' => $detials[1]),
    array('Description' => $detials[2]),
    array('Description' => $detials[3])
 );
```